Not able set throttling limits in AWS OpenSearch
I am using AWS OpenSearch with ML model. While creating ES cluster there is no parameter as
cluster_manager.throttling.thresholds.delete_index 
in _cluster/settings.
To Deploy ML model, we have to run "plugins.ml_commons.only_run_on_ml_node": false but it is creating default "cluster_manager.throttling.thresholds.delete_index" to 50 in cluster settings under persistent parameters which eventually deletes the index automatically.
To update this parameter. I am not able to adjust these cluster settings related to threshold task limits to -1 (which shall disable the task).
Example : To set throttling limit for delete-index task to -1 :
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
   "cluster_manager.throttling.thresholds": {
      "delete-index": {
        "value": -1
      }
    }
  }
}

It gives error,
{
"Message": "Your request: '/_cluster/settings' payload is not allowed."
}
Can someone please let me know how to disable the index deletion automatically or update delete-index param in cluster setting?

As a managed service, AOS allowed limited settings to be controlled by users. Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/supported-operations.html#version_opensearch_2.11
